# What SQL privileges is it best to use to satisy requirements of most popular CMS

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, privileges, sql-grant

What privileges is it better to use to satisfy the requirements of most popular Content Management Systems?

Is it safe to say:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON siteX.* TO siteX@localhost
```

Or better to use something like:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER,
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES,
      EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE
  ON siteX.* TO siteX@localhost
```

Comment: Perhaps you should spell out what you mean by CMS — the Wikipedia disambiguation page has 14 entries in the _Computing_ category.

Comment: The CMS itself should be able to do anything to its own database. It's the *users* you need to specify privileges for, and probably in the CMS rather than the database.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the CMS to a very large extent (assuming you mean content management system).

Keep in mind however that specific requirements may vary with implementations.  For example for some things, delete may not be something you want to support.

This being said, *usually* in the most common case, you want to support all database operations on all tables the CMS expects to use.  Again, that is not always the case.  You need to take individual instance requirements into account.